# Applying the Spot Healing Brush Tool over a selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

It's possible to apply the effect of the **Paint Bucket Tool** on a selection. This imitates the process of selecting each and every individual pixel in the selection, clicking on it once, and changing its color.

Is it possible to do the same with the **Spot Healing Brush**? Meaning, make a selection, and imitate the process of clicking each and every individual pixel in that selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bad misconception there. Spot healing brush is allways an area processing tool, it never concentrates only to a single pixel like the painting tools can do. Healing brush tries to find a different spot which is surrounded by mutually equal pixels. If it finds one, it fixes the "out of the general color" spot. Of course the brush can have one pixel size, but in that case it anyway checks 8 surrounding pixels.

Making a selection before applying spot healing brush only prevents the healing outside the selection, but your brush must fly over every spot which you want to be healed.

If you have large single color area which contains unwanted small spots, you can in theory make a large healing brush which covers the whole healing area and make a selection to protect other areas. The result unfortunately will be crappy because regardless of the selection, the brush can think some color outside the selection as the right one.

=> If I need by selection limited healing, I try to make cloning instead.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was not clear enough. Here is the process I have now: I detect "spots" in the image that I want to "heal' so I click on each and every one of them. However, I *am* able to create a selection for all of those spots. So I wonder, do I really have to click on each and every one of them or could I somehow use the selection and make the "Spot healing brush" apply to it? Am I clear enough? :\

Comment: @Sipo Adjust your brush to have an enormous size. Make your selection and click with the brush and see. The effect is limited to the selection, but the result can still be quite surprising because you have no control on "the right color". A script programmer obviously could find from the selection the islands which need healing and write a code which heals them one by one. Unfortunately I am not a programmer.

Comment: I actually am a programmer, but I didn't know you could write code for photoshop... Where could I found information about this?

Comment: @Sipo Check this. It a t least seems complex https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html